# Minecraft won't download on SSD

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, hard-drive

When I open Minecraft and try to download it, it will only let me download in C: and won't let me download in D: SSD.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Where are you downloading it from?

Comment: Can you share the error you are getting as well when trying to download?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your primary location for downloads are your SSD.
You can do that by going to system then storage then change primary location.